# How to fail job if any dependent job fails

Tags: github-actions

I have a test workflow that has the following job structure:

```yaml
jobs:
  set_matrix:
    . . .  # Defines the test environments
  test:
    needs: set_matrix
    . . .  # Runs as N parallel jobs each of which performs the test in one test environment
  test_finish:
    needs: test
    . . .  # Runs when all parallel test jobs are complete, and performs things like finish coveralls.
```

Now I want to enable auto-merge on the master branch. This requires that I have a safe way to detect that the test workflow has succeeded. I want to do this by specifying a required job in the branch rules.

Because the set of test environments that is set up in the `set_matrix` job may vary, I do not want to require the success for each of the resulting `test` jobs in the branch rules.

Instead, I would like to require only the success of the `test_finish` job.

I thought that because its success depends on the success of its dependent jobs, that would work automatically. However, it does not. What actually happens is that when one or more of the `test` jobs fail, the `test_finish` job is skipped. That would not be a problem in and of itself, but it becomes a problem because skipped jobs count as a success for the branch rule, and so the PR would be auto-merged even though a `test` job has failed (I actually verified this).

I have tried multiple ways to deal with that, none of which worked:

1. Use `failure()` in `test_finish`:

   ```yaml
   jobs:
     set_matrix:
       . . .
     test:
       needs: set_matrix
       . . .
     test_finish:
       needs: test
       if: "!cancelled()"  # Run always except if workflow is cancelled - works
       steps:
         - name: Fail if any test job has failed
           if: failure()  # does not work
           run: exit 1
         . . .
   ```

   The [`failure()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#failure) method is documented as:

   > Returns true when any previous step of a job fails. If you have a chain of dependent jobs, failure() returns true if any ancestor job fails.

   Sounds like exactly what I need, since `test` is a dependent job of `test_failure`. However it does not work: it did not return true if the dependent `test` jobs failed.

   For the full test workflow using this approach, see https://github.com/pywbem/nocaselist/pull/134
2. Marker step in test job:

   ```yaml
   jobs:
     set_matrix:
       . . .
     test:
       needs: set_matrix
       steps:
         . . .
         - name: Mark job result  # Last step in job
           id: test_result
           run: exit 0
     test_finish:
       needs: test
       if: "!cancelled()"  # Run always except if workflow is cancelled - works
       steps:
         - name: Fail if any test job has failed
           if: "steps.test_result.outcome != 'success'"  # does not work
           run: exit 1
         . . .
   ```

   It turns out that this always causes the check step in the `test_finish` job to fail, even when all `test` jobs succeeded. It is also not clear to me how the `steps.test_result.outcome` expression handles the fact that there are multiple `test` jobs each of which has a `test_result` id.

   For the full test workflow using this approach, see https://github.com/pywbem/nocaselist/pull/133

So my questions are:

- How can I fail the `test_finish` job when one or more of the `test` jobs have failed?
- Or more generally: in this scenario with `set_matrix` and N parallel `test` jobs, how can I define a branch rule that correctly detects whether all `test` jobs (and the `test_finish` job) have succeeded, without specifying every single one of them in the rule?

Comment: To get data from the `test` jobs in `test_finish` you'd need to give each one [_outputs_](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) (with unique names, otherwise last one wins - see [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26639)). Then you access them via the `needs` context - `steps.test_result` would have to be a step with that ID _in the same job_.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe for the quick answer. I'll try that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The problem with using "outputs" is that my job matrix is dynamic, so I cannot create unique output identifiers upfront. I have tried two of the actions plugins mentioned in the other link you provided, but so far none of them worked for all environments. See https://github.com/pywbem/nocaselist/pull/137 and https://github.com/pywbem/nocaselist/pull/138